# how to receive json object from android using POST method

Tags: php, android

I am working on a php script which receives data sent by android in json format using POST method.
But i am not getting any data, here is my code

```
$josn = file_get_contents("php://input");   
$json_data = json_decode($josn, true);
```

i just tried to print $json_data by

```
print_r($json_data);
```

but its not showing any values

Comment: Can you post your android code that sends json data?   Not sure what are you doing with `file_get_contents()`. Because this method only reads the specified file. So need to know how you are sending json output. you can try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25449468/i-trying-to-send-this-json-data-form-android-to-php-server                            There should be a form element name. Based on which you should catch post data. Thanks

Comment: You probably want php to check the $_POST global variable for your contents.

Comment: The first statement is ok. The second can not work as $json contains mostly more than json text. The first thing that you should do  after the first statement is `echo($json);`. Remove all other statements. Then in your client read the echo from the inputstream and compare.

Comment: file_get_contents() offers a lot more than simply getting a specified file.  It reads the input buffer for example.  He is using it perfectly in his statement to fetch the json that was delivered in the POST request... assuming he is sending the right headers with his POST request to treat it like json and not multipart form data. Web URLs, files via FTP, SFTP, are all supported by file_get_contents().  So saying he is using it incorrectly is blatantly incorrect. @user119247

Answer (score 0):

`var_dump()` is much more reliable than `print_r()`

Whether the data is corrupt or not, it will tell you 'something' about the thing you are trying to see.

If it is *null* it will say '**null**'.

If it is '*bob*' it will say **(string 3) 'bob'**.

If it is *4* it will say **(int) 4**

If it is '*4*' it will say **(string 1) '4'**

Also, your `json_decode()` might be breaking if the input is not valid json. A safer way to see if you are getting any data at all is to dump and check your data before you pass it into the `json_decode()` function:

```
var_dump( file_get_contents("php://input") );
```

If you see valid json, then it is safe to pass your **$josn** variable into the `json_decode()` function.

### Bonus

Seems dumb but it's worth mentioning that you can only use `file_get_contents()` on the input buffer once and then the contents are gone. If you try to read them again, they will be null. Refer to the variable you stored them in when you first read them.

### Separetely

Another fellow mentioned checking your global $_POST[] variable... which brings up a great point.  Headers!

For json pickup with `file_get_contents('php://input')`, php needs your android app to send the header:

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
```

For POST variable pickup with `$_POST[]`, php needs your android app to send the header:

```
header('Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
```

OR

```
header('Content-Type: multipart/form-data');
```